# Get click event from SVG bounding box using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add a mouse click event listener to click events on the bounding box of an SVG element (in this case all elements of the class "measure").
What I thought should work is this:

```
 var vrvToolkit = new verovio.toolkit(); // www.verovio.org

 jQuery.ajax({
     url: "http://www.verovio.org/examples/downloads/Schubert_Lindenbaum.mei",
     success: function (data) {
         var svg = vrvToolkit.renderData(data + "\n", "");
         jQuery("#svg_output").html(svg);
     },
     async: false
 });

 d3.select("#svg_output svg").selectAll(".measure")
     .on("click", function () {
     jQuery("#log").text(d3.mouse(this));
 });
```

[see JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78hLhugh/)

Unfortunately only mouse clicks on actually drawn elements are registered, the white space is ignored.

Is there a way to recognize mouse clicks inside a specific bounding box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot detect clicks on none existing elements in d3.

If you want to detect your bounding box, you need to create a new element with the same shape (for example: `<polygon>`), make it invisible and add it to the group you want to listen to.

Usually people create a big transparent rectangle.

Comment: Thanks. Not the answer I was hoping for, but very helpful.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you more, are you seeking to directly listen to events of a selection's bounding box ? Because I really don't think this is natively possible in d3.

Comment: I managed to make my overlay layer and am now able to react on bounding box clicks. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding ! :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add the `click` handler on the entire SVG and not specific elements:

```
d3.select("#svg_output svg")
  .on("click", function () {
  jQuery("#log").text(d3.mouse(this));
});
```

Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/78hLhugh/2/). To get the element that is being clicked on, you can use `d3.event.target` (https://jsfiddle.net/78hLhugh/3/).

Comment: Thanks for the efford, but this way I don't get the actual element that I am clicking on. I don't need the mouse position, this was only to minimize my code example in the question.

Comment: Well you should have said that in the first place then -- you can use `d3.event.target` to get the actual element, see my updated answer.